# Setting Recursion Flag in Process Builder prevents Process Builder from Running Flow

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, recursion

I have a process builder and flow combo I have been building. I finally got it to work, but had to turn off the **Recursive** Flag on the opportunity in order to get the flow to be scheduled from the Process Builder.

However, some forums on StackExchange makes me wonder if this could significantly hamper my Process Builder and Scheduled Flow that is called from the Process Builder.

It is worth mentioning that we have 3 Process Builders running on our Opportunity Object. One for emails, and another for Opportunity Processes.

Any advice on this subject would be great.

Comment:  Imo having multiple process builder on same object is discouraged, what's stopping you from making them one? Is update from one process builder triggering second process builder?

Comment: Yes, but they run on different Opportunity Record Types.